# Is it possible to make your own custom native object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to make your own custom native object like String, Number, Array, Date and etc..?

I want to make an object as to directly use it's native value, I already read about Object.valueOf and how to make use of it but it can only be used on operations if you try to send the object using ajax, it will send the whole object along with its prototypes and I don't want that

Lets say for example I have a phone object

```
function Phone(a){
   this.value=a;
}

Phone.prototype={
    getAreaCode:function(){
       return this.value.substr(0,3);
    }
}

var a = new Phone('938-358-395');
console.log(a);
//I want the output here to be '938-358-395' instead of Phone{value:'938-358-395'}
// just like how a Date Object would normally go when you do this

var b = new Date();
console.log(b);
//output would be 'Sun Dec 16 2018 20:20:28 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)')

//as what I've said earlier I want to send it via ajax like this

var c = {
    phone1: new Phone('938-358-395'),
    phone2: new Phone('938-358-394')
};

//now I want to send c via ajax but the outcome will be
//{phone1: Phone {value:'938-358-395'},phone2: Phone {value:'938-358-394'}}
//what I want is {phone1: '938-358-395', phone2: '938-358-394'}
```

Comment: What are you using to serialize `c` for use in ajax? JSON? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to send c via ajax

The answer varies depending on how you're serializing `c` to send it via ajax, since of course you need to send *text*.

If you're using JSON, you can implement a `toJSON` method, which `JSON.stringify` will use:

```js
function Phone(a){
   this.value=a;
}

Phone.prototype={
    constructor: Phone,
    getAreaCode:function(){
       return this.value.substr(0,3);
    },
    toJSON: function() {
       return this.value;
    }
};

var c = {
    phone1: new Phone('938-358-395'),
    phone2: new Phone('938-358-394')
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(c));
```

If you're using other serializations, they probably result in converting the `Phone` object to a string, so implementing `toString` does it:

```js
function Phone(a){
   this.value=a;
}

Phone.prototype={
    constructor: Phone,
    getAreaCode:function(){
       return this.value.substr(0,3);
    },
    toString: function() {
       return this.value;
    }
};

var c = {
    phone1: new Phone('938-358-395'),
    phone2: new Phone('938-358-394')
};

// Not just doing String(c), since c doesn't implement toString
console.log(String(c.phone1) + ", " + String(c.phone2));
```

Or of course, implement both:

```js
function Phone(a){
   this.value=a;
}

Phone.prototype={
    constructor: Phone,
    getAreaCode:function(){
       return this.value.substr(0,3);
    },
    toJSON: function() {
       return this.toString();
    },
    toString: function() {
       return this.value;
    }
};

var c = {
    phone1: new Phone('938-358-395'),
    phone2: new Phone('938-358-394')
};

// Not just doing String(c), since c doesn't implement toString
console.log(String(c.phone1) + ", " + String(c.phone2));
console.log(JSON.stringify(c));
```

---

Side note: If you completely replace the `prototype` property of your constructor function, be sure to repair the `constructor` property so it's pointing to the correct function. Note the `constructor: Phone` I've added to the snippets above.

Of course, here in 2018 (nearly 2019), you can use `class` syntax, transpiling if you need to support old browsers:

```
class Phone {
    constructor(a) {
        this.value = a;
    }
    getAreaCode() {
        return this.value.substr(0, 3);
    }
    toJSON() {
        return this.toString();
    }
    toString() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: can I do the constructor on the prototype? Since I'm used to the prototype approach instead of classes. I still find using Class quite confusing so I'm sticking to the old way of doing it.

Comment: and is it really important to repair the constructor property? what for? I'm not familiar with it sorry, I've been programming javascript for almost 2 years now and I don't really do that.

Comment: @ShinichiGarcia - *"can I do the constructor on the prototype?"* Yes, that's what the answer does above. *"and is it really important to repair the constructor property"* In general, it's best practice. It used to be that JavaScript itself set `constructor` but didn't use it for anything. That's not true anymore, though the things it uses it for aren't likely to relate to your `Phone` class specifically, but again, it's best practice.

Comment: @NikosM. - Yes, I covered `toString` in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with "nativeness", the JavaScript interpreter includes symbols like `Number`, `String` etc from the portfolio of symbols defined by ECMA, the standards body that de-facto specifies the JavaScript language these days. Yes, the symbols are part of the language, but are provided by the user agent. In addition to these, there is a portfolio of symbols that are provided as part of the "Web platform" -- whatever the user agent chooses to implement and include that is defined in different Web APIs, including the `JSON` symbol.

JavaScript is perfectly content letting you define your own symbols, including classes.

The misunderstanding on your part is expecting the `Console` API, exposed primarily through the `console` global, to behave the way you expect it to when provided your `Phone` objects. It's not going to do that. `console.log` (and other console functions of similar function, like `debug`, `warn`, `info` etc) internally interprets what class of object it is, and plugs into the Developer Tools to show the object in a convenient way.

For any class of object defined by you, the class does not fall into the set of classes it will interpret in a special way, it will simply tell you what class of objects these are, and their internal composition -- its properties, typically.

You can control how the object will be dumped by `console.log` as a string -- using `JSON.stringify` or `toString` or however else you want the string to be.

Or you can define your own `Console` class, and override `console` behavior like that, where, encountering `Phone` objects you can show them with your custom formatting. But you cannot expect the internal `console` object to recognize your `Phone` objects as some special class -- for it, they're objects of a class that is a subtype of `Object`, that's all.